# Java Regex look-behinds

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I have the following regular expression `(?s)^(?<=.*Exception.*)<The server started in RUNNING mode.>`, so basically I want to find any `Exception` that was thrown before the server starts running.

I have a test log file that is supposed to match the given regular expression but does not match. How I match is that I read the whole log file into a string and the apply the regex on this string.

Is there something I am missing on this regular expression?

Example input:

Should Match

```
Sep 25, 2014 9:17:28 AM za.co.hide.health.common.cache.impl.ReadAccessorImpl initializeCache
INFO: Finished Caching cache.name.treatment.protocol.limit.period: 7 items cached
Sep 25, 2014 9:17:29 AM org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean destroy
INFO: Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
Sep 25, 2014 9:17:29 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [hide.health.clinicalsystem.bcl.treatmentProtocolService]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hide.health.clinicalsystem.bcl.treatmentProtocolService' defined in URL [file:/J:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/AUTH/servers/AUTH_SER/tmp/_WL_user/treatment_protocol_deployment_ear/fctudi/APP-INF/classes/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocol' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'treatmentProtocolActivationDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocolActivationDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'treatmentProtocolDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocolDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'protocolStagesDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'protocolStagesDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:387)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:222)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:414)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:99)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
.
.
.
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The server has successfully established a connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 172.22.9.37:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:688a:1e43:b337:a3b:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <The hostname "DHTBMS02.hide.holdings.co.za", maps to multiple IP addresses: 172.22.9.37, fe80:0:0:0:688a:1e43:b337:a3b%12.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:ac16:925:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started the WebLogic Server Administration Server "AUTH_SER" for domain "AUTH" running in development mode.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>
```

Should not match

```
<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The server has successfully established a connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:30 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 172.22.9.37:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:688a:1e43:b337:a3b:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <The hostname "DHTBMS02.hide.holdings.co.za", maps to multiple IP addresses: 172.22.9.37, fe80:0:0:0:688a:1e43:b337:a3b%12.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:ac16:925:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started the WebLogic Server Administration Server "AUTH_SER" for domain "AUTH" running in development mode.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
    <Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>
Sep 25, 2014 9:17:28 AM za.co.hide.health.common.cache.impl.ReadAccessorImpl initializeCache
    INFO: Finished Caching cache.name.treatment.protocol.limit.period: 7 items cached
    Sep 25, 2014 9:17:29 AM org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean destroy
    INFO: Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
    Sep 25, 2014 9:17:29 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [hide.health.clinicalsystem.bcl.treatmentProtocolService]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hide.health.clinicalsystem.bcl.treatmentProtocolService' defined in URL [file:/J:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/AUTH/servers/AUTH_SER/tmp/_WL_user/treatment_protocol_deployment_ear/fctudi/APP-INF/classes/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocol' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'treatmentProtocolActivationDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocolActivationDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'treatmentProtocolDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'treatmentProtocolDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'protocolStagesDTOBuilder' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'protocolStagesDTOBuilder' defined in class path resource [spring/treatment-protocol-core-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:387)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:222)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:414)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:191)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:99)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: post your input and expected result too

Comment: java won't allow quantifiers inside lookbehind.

Comment: and exmple input will be much appreciated

Comment: Memory wise, it's probably not a good idea to read an entire log file into a String. Why don't you scan line for line until you find your "RUNNING" line?

Comment: Please see the question again for example input... couln't upload to a sharing site because they all have been blocked.

Comment: @Davio, I only want exceptions before the server starts, If I read line by line and do the checking, I also get exceptions that occurred after server startup. The log file won't be that big at the time of scanning, but I agree, it can use up a lot of memory

Comment: Only line I see there in `should match` section is **<Sep 25, 2014 9:17:31 AM CAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>** and it doesn't even have any **Exception** can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed.

better remove the `.*`

```
(?s)(?<=Exception)<The server started in RUNNING mode.>
```

Suppose you want to capture all the exceptions in the log

use this :

```
[\w]+Exception
```

there is no need of using lookaheads or lookbehinds.

update:

If you are only concerned to know if the server started with exception or not I guess this will do it for you:

```
(Exception[\s\S]*?The server started in RUNNING mode)
```

you will get a match in the previous string but not in the second one.

Comment: Yea, something like `NullPointerException`or `RuntimeException`

Comment: @anubhava thats upto the OP to decide whether he wants it from the beginning or anywhere else

Comment: @RatshiḓahoWayne anyway I have updated the regex, better see if this works for you, I will get back if you find any problem

Comment: Good to see you fixed it but now this regex looks *different* from what OP may need.

Comment: @aelor, still not matching anything, please see update question for test input

Comment: @aelor, it does match, but I want one which only matches if it is before  <The server started in RUNNING mode.>. In your case, it will macth all exceptions, even after  <The server started in RUNNING mode.>

Comment: @RatshiḓahoWayne check my update sir, hope this solves your query

Answer (score 1):

Lookaheads and lookbehinds are **both** zero-width. However one is allowed a regular expression inside a lookahead, but not in a lookbehind (at least, not unless it is a fixed-length regexp). The reason for this is simply that most regexp engines are not designed to apply regexps backward.

In fact there are exceptions to this rule, and some engines will support the  OP's regexp. However, unless you are using one of these exceptional regexp engines, then you cannot have a variable length regexp (i.e. a regexp that can match a variable length substring) in your lookbehind, which is the problem with the OP's original regexp.

A good explanation of lookaround can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

You can solve the problem without using a lookbehind. Try this expression:

`(\w+Exception).*<The server started in RUNNING mode.>`

This matches if an exception happened before the servers started in RUNNING mode, and also captures the first such exception in a group. If all you want to do is ascertain that an exception occurred, you could drop the round brackets.

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to do what I want to do using regular expression?

Comment: Well, found a way to do it using two regular expression, but it would have been nice to have one regular expression to do the job.

Comment: I updated my answer with a single regular expression that I hope will solve the problem